# Is it possible to use Nerd Fonts as the font for Terminals in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, ide, settings

Afternoon!

First, I hope everyone is well.

I am currently experimenting with **Visual Studio** [`Version: 17.5.0 Preview 4.0`] (to clarify, *not* Visual Studio Code) and was hoping to utilize a [**Nerd Font**](https://www.nerdfonts.com/), specifically **CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font**, for my Terminal. This is so [**Oh-My-Posh**](https://ohmyposh.dev/) will have the necessary icons to display correctly.

[image: Screenshot of Oh-My-Posh interface not rendering correctly in Visual Studio’s]

However, it seems that **Visual Studio** does ***not*** allow **Nerd Fonts** as a font for the **Terminal**. If you look in the attached screenshots below, you can see that the setting’s dropdown does not list **Nerd Fonts** as options. Curiously, they *are* available as a choice for the Text Editor.

[image: Screenshot displaying Nerd Fonts being available for the Text Editor in Visual Studio]
[image: Screenshot displaying Nerd Fonts not being available for the Terminal in Visual Studio]

Regarding to solve it myself, I have *scoured* the Visual Studio documentation and tried my best Google-fu to find any results. Disappointingly most search engines return results concerning Visual Studio, *not* Visual Studio Code.

Before I submit a report to the developers of Visual Studio, I would like to cover all my bases and make sure I am not missing something.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve it? Same issue here... :/

Comment: Wow, really fast update but after installing this one https://eng.m.fontke.com/font/64992431/download/ (TTF) it worked! Now I was able to select the font for terminal and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing a TTF-font ***will make it available to select for the Visual Studio Terminal*** via the Fonts and Colors-settings.

Installing OTF-font files will make them appear for text editors in visual studio, but not the terminal.

*Jan's guess in his answer is in fact correct.*

Answer (score 5):

Wild guess here. They might still be on conhost which doesn't work with OTF files and needs TTF. So, theoretically, installing the same font as TTF could do the trick. You'll need to do a manual install from the [Nerd Font repo](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/CascadiaCode) in this case as they don't ship the TTF files inside their zip files.

Comment: The legend himself. Thanks for responding quickly! Testing this out now. Will update promptly on the result. By the way, the [Nerd Font repo](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/CascadiaCode) you linked *only* has `.otf` files for the font **Caskaydia Cove**, unless I am missing something. Its not a problem, I just converted the already existing **Caskaydia Cove** `.otf` fonts to `.ttf`. Will report back as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, that proposed solution did not work. Oh well, it was worth a shot. Thanks though for the reply. Take care!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and am switching from CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font to Hack Nerd Font following advice on a thread I am following. https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/785#issuecomment-1547609558 shows this is a confirmed bug. I will report back if it works.

Comment: Good to know. I personally just resolved to using the JetBrains.

Comment: Continue with JetBrains = switching fonts didn't work

Answer (score 0):

After installing the [Hack Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.0.2/Hack.zip), I managed to resolve the issue by adjusting the terminal settings in Visual Studio.
The key step involves specifying the font to be used by the **terminal**. Here's how you can do the same:

1. Navigate to `Tools` > `Options`.
2. Select the `Terminal` section.
3. Under `Font and Colors`, choose `Hack Nerd Font` from the dropdown menu for the font.

This configuration ensures that Visual Studio Code's terminal uses the Hack Nerd Font, which includes a wide range of glyphs and symbols needed for proper display. Below is a screenshot that illustrates where these settings are located:

[image: Settings image]

By following these steps, you should be able to use the Hack Nerd Font in Visual Studio Code's terminal, improving legibility and access to various font glyphs necessary for development tasks.